# Is the truth table method for valuating 0th order sentences not a proof system in its own right?

Tags: logic, propositional-logic

This might sound a bit opinionated or a bit too pedantic, but in every book (that I've looked at) about propositional logic, usually this chain of events happens:

- Discuss the alphabet and grammar of 0th order logic
- Discuss how to evaluate a sentence's truth value given an assignment (ex. True and True is True)
- **Discuss the method of truth tables to show that two sentences are semantically equivalent** - Here lies my problem, this method is not presented as a proof system in many texts I've seen.
- **Discuss the notion of a proof system to help us deal with the intractability of truth tables**

We usually say that prop. logic is *sound* and *complete* but hear me out: These properties depend on two specific "methods" (for a lack of better word) - The first is the truth table method, and the other is the proof system we choose. **Perhaps we choose truth tables because they're clean and easy to understand?** Truth tables are nice, but don't extrapolate well for more complicated logics.

It turns out there's a lot of equivalent proof systems for prop. logic. So let's suppose we pick one and put it on the "semantic" pedestal. Call it X. Now we pick another one, Y, and call it our "proof system". Now we can talk about whether these two are sound and complete again, because even though they're both proof systems, we chose one to be "what we mean" by a sentence.

So hence the question: Why do we not introduce semantic evaluation of statements as a proof system itself? Is it because tables are too cumbersome in general to describe in terms of inference rules?

Comment: Yes, it is. If with proof system we mean a "tool" the produce/verify *valid* formulas, then truth table algorithm will do it for propositional tautologies.

Comment: As you say, the "standard" approach is to build a proof system (either axioms + rules or rules only) to generate formulas and then link it to semantics through the completeness theorem: this approach holds in general, also in cases where there is no mechanical procedure to test for validity.

Comment: We not introduce semantic evaluation as a proof system because it does not function as such beyond some simple extensions of propositional logic. Already for predicate logic, let alone set theory, semantic evaluation requires evaluations over infinite domains that can not be encoded into finite chains of inferences from a finite (or at least finitely generatable) set of axioms that we want in a proof system. Even in propositional logic such a presentation of truth tables is rather unnatural, albeit possible. And already semantics of arithmetic can not be captured by any nice proof system.